# Calling a python script from awk

Tags: python, awk

I have a file without about 150k rows, and two columns.  I need to to run a a python script on the first field, and save its output as a third column, such that the change looks like this:

Original File:

```
Col1  Col2 
d     2
e     4
f     6

New file:


Col1  Col2  Col3
d     2     output
e     4     output
f     6     output
```

I'm not able to run the script from inside awk.

```
cat original.list | awk -F" " ' {`/homes/script.py $1`}'
```

If I were able to, I would then want to save it as a variable, and print the new variable, plus $1 and $2 to the new file.

thanks in advance (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870215/calling-python-script-from-awk))

Comment: See this: [Assigning system command's output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable)

Comment: Why don't you do all the tasks with python? Awk is not the only language which can split columns.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the "related question" you linked (and the one posted in the comments) actually solve your problem,
it just need to be adapted to your specific case.

> ```
> cat original.list | awk -F" " ' {`/homes/script.py $1`}'
> ```

- `cat` is useless here because `awk` can open and read the file by itself
- you don't need `-F" "` because `awk` will split fields by spaces by default
- backticks `` wont run your script, [that's a shell (discouraged)
  feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/), doesn't work in
  `awk`

we can use `command | getline var` to execute a command and store its
(first line of) output in a variable. from `man awk`:

> command | getline var
>
> pipes a record from command into var.

using your example file:

```
$ cat original
Col1  Col2
d     2
e     4
f     6
$
```

and a dummy `script.py`:

```
$ cat script.py
#!/bin/python

print("output")
$
```

we can do something like this:

```
$ awk '
NR == 1 { print $0, "Col3" }
NR > 1 { cmd="./script.py " $1; cmd | getline out; close(cmd); print $0, out }
' original
Col1  Col2 Col3
d     2 output
e     4 output
f     6 output
$
```

the first action runs on the first line of input, adds `Col3` to the header and
avoids passing `Col1` to the python script.

in the other action, we first build the command concatenating `$1` to the
script's path, then we run it and store its first line of output in `out`
variable (I'm assuming your python script output is just one line).  `close(cmd)` is important because after `getline`, the pipe reading
from `cmd`'s output would remain open and doing this for many records could lead
to errors like `too many open files`. at the end we print `$0` and `cmd`'s
output.

third's column formatting looks a bit off, you can improve it either from
`awk` using `printf` or with an external program like `column`, e.g:

```
$ awk '
NR == 1 { print $0, "Col3" }
NR > 1 { cmd="./script.py " $1; cmd | getline out; close(cmd); print $0, out }
' original | column -t
Col1  Col2  Col3
d     2     output
e     4     output
f     6     output
$
```

lastly, doing all this on a 150k rows file means calling the python script 150k
times etc.., it probably will be a slow task, I think performance could be
improved by doing everything directly in the python script as already
suggested in the comments, but whether or not it is applicable to your specific case, goes
beyond the scope of this question/answer.